# XCode 4 - 'Include Unit Tests'

Tags: xcode

I just upgraded to XCode 4 and I was wondering if I need to 'include unit tests' when setting up an application? Also, what does that mean exactly?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You do not **need** to include unit tests.

---

What does "unit testing" mean? (from the [unit-testing](/questions/tagged/unit-testing) [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unit-testing/info))

> Unit testing is a method by which individual units of source code are tested to determine if they are fit for use. A unit is the smallest testable part of an application. In procedural programming a unit may be an individual function or procedure. Unit tests are created by programmers or occasionally by white box testers.
>
> Ideally, each [test case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_case) is independent from the others: substitutes like [method stubs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_stub), [mock objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object), [fakes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object#Mocks_and_fakes) and [test harnesses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_harness) can be used to assist testing a module in isolation. Unit tests are typically written and run by software developers to ensure that code meets its design and behaves as intended.<sup>[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing)</sup>
>
> Unit testing is closely related to [Test Driven Development](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TestDrivenDevelopment).

---

[@ToddH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/428767/toddh) points out:

> It's easier to include [unit tests] when you setup the project. If you do it later there are quite a few steps involved in doing it correctly: [http://twobitlabs.com/2011/06/...](http://twobitlabs.com/2011/06/adding-ocunit-to-an-existing-ios-project-with-xcode-4/)

Thanks for the protip, Todd!

Comment: It's easier to include them when you setup the project. If you do it later there are quite a few steps involved in doing it correctly: http://twobitlabs.com/2011/06/adding-ocunit-to-an-existing-ios-project-with-xcode-4/